# Navigation breaks into new line

Tags: html, css, navigation

The navigation breaks into a second line as soon as I add "margin-right: 4%" in "nav li" - if I use px instead of % the problem won't occur, eg.: "margin-right: 10px" . I am not sure why this is happening

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k93K2/

```
<header>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="logo">
                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/220x80"/></a>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div><!--container-->
</header>
```

--

```
.container {
    max-width: 1070px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#logo {
    float: left;
}

nav {
    float: right;
}

nav li {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 4%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this ?

```
header{
    width: 100%;       /* initialization */
    min-width: 590px;  /* some min width */
}

.container {
    max-width: 1070px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#logo {
    float: left;
}

nav {
    width: calc(190px + 20%);  /* width of nav is (4x5)% + size of "HomeServicesGalleryTeamContact" */
    min-width: 370px;          /* set some min width */
    float: right;
}


nav li {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 4%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the problem with your code is margin and padding `<ul>` tag. So you need to remove `margin` and `padding` in `<ul>` like below:

```
nav {
    float: left;
    width: 220px;
}    
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Please try!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried your suggestion and it doesn't seem to do the trick. The problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

`%` takes value relative to it's container width....
so when you given `4%` margin, then it applies to all `li` and pushes right margin to `4%` according to container width!

To prevent content breaking into new line, i would suggest to apply `white-space:nowrap` to

[**example demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/k93K2/2/)

```
header {
     overflow: hidden;
     white-space:nowrap; /*added*/
}

nav ul {
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:nowrap;/*added*/
    border:1px solid red;
}
```